# Own objects into QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I would like to have a drag-and-drop feature based on images. If I drag and drop an image I would like to know which image I picked out and moved with (a simple std::string will do to uniquely identify the object that that image is representing). My thought is to store my own object (QPixmapItem) in the QGraphicsScene:

```
#ifndef QPIXMAPITEM_H
#define QPIXMAPITEM_H

#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QPoint>

class QPixmapItem : public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
public:
    QPixmapItem(std::string path, std::string id, int x, int y);
    std::string getIdentifier (){return this->identifier;}
    QPoint getPosition () const{return this->position;}

private:
    std::string identifier;
    QPoint position;
};

#endif // QPIXMAPITEM_H
```

This is the method I use to add my objects to the scene:

```
void MainWindow::addPixmapItemToScene(std::string path, int x, int y)
{
    // generate pixmap item & add it to the scene
    QPixmapItem *item = new QPixmapItem(path, std::string("id123"), x, y);
    ui->roomView->scene()->addItem(item);

    // only update the affected area
    ui->roomView->updateSceneRect(item->pixmap().rect());
}
```

Here is how I try to 'catch' the object at a QMouseEvent:

```
void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    std::cout << "mouse pressed" << std::endl;

    QGraphicsPixmapItem *currentItem = dynamic_cast<QGraphicsPixmapItem *>(childAt(event->pos()));
    if (!currentItem) {
        return;
    }
    std::cout << "item pressed" << std::endl;
}
```

The objects are being added to the scene but whenever I press them, the final line ("item pressed") never makes it onto the screen..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QGraphicsItem` already support moving by way of drag-and-drop within a `QGraphicsScene`. All you need is set the [`QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum) flag.

If you want to get notified when that happens, override [`QGraphicsItem::itemChange()`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#itemChange) in your custom `QGraphicsItem`.

Comment: It seems once the scene is setup and all my custom QGraphicsItem's are drawn, QGraphicsItem::itemChange() never is entered again...

Comment: Solved, had to set this flag: setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsScenePositionChanges);

Answer (score 0):

childAt() won't work because it returns a QWidget, and QGraphicsPixMapItems are not QWidgets (therefore childAt() will never return a pointer to any kind of QGraphicsItem, and even if it somehow did, the dynamic_cast conversion would return NULL anyway).

In order to get a list of QGraphicsItems that intersect a specified point in the scene, call [QGraphicsScene::items()](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#items-3) on your scene object.  Then iterate through the returned list to find out what QGraphicsPixMapItems (if any) are in it.